# Method exists but Ruby says it is undefined

Tags: ruby, methods

I am currently a beginner at Ruby and I am currently stuck with an assignment. I am remaking mastermind in ruby.However, I am struggling to understand the syntax completely.When I try to call the method it tells me it is undefined. I tried reading through some other questions here but none of the solutions helped me as my problem is a bit different.
I made a class first:

```
class Mastermind
```

Then I made the methods inside it.

```
        def check
        result=Array.new(4)
        i=0
        while i<5
          if chooseWord[i]==userAnswer[i]
            result[0]="exact"
            i=i+1
          end
          puts result[0]
        end
        checkingResult=check.new
      end

  def userAnswer
    puts "What is your guess? "
    word = gets.chomp
    guess="Your guess was #{word}"
    userAnswer=guess.chars.to_a
    return userAnswer
  end

  def chooseWord
    lines = File.readlines("02-word-list.txt" )
    chosen=lines.sample
    puts chosen
    chooseWord=chosen.chars.to_a
    return chooseWord
  end
```

And after that I called the method I wanted inside the class.

```
check.method
```

The error I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `check' for Mastermind:Class (NameError)
```

But also outside of it just to see if anything changes which it didn't. Sorry if this is a stupid question as well but I am very confused. I wanted my methods to act like void methods and then be called if that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And after that I called the method I wanted inside the class.
>
> ```
> check.method
> ```

Seems like you tried to call the method within the class body via:

```
class Mastermind
  def check
    # ...
  end

  check.method
end
```

First of all, you don't have to append `.method` to call a method, just write the method's name.

But calling `check` within the class body doesn't work either because `check` is an *instance* method. In order to call it, you have to create an instance first, e.g.:

```
mm = Mastermind.new
mm.check
```